# Spring MVC, jsp rendering taking time

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, jstl

We have a page hosted on Spring MVC based stack. Part of the code parses a json structure which defines the set of html elements to be rendered, like dropdown, checkbox etc.
There are dynamic includes (jsp:include) extensively used in this code, which are also recursive.
During peak traffic hours, widget rendering time shoots up to 10000 milliseconds from normal 500 ms.
After initial investigation it’s evident that thread switching between rendering of the included jsp and jsp which includes them is taking time.

Anyone have faced similar issues?
Any info about how the rendering pool thread count is defined will be helpful

Comment: did you verify your findings with any performance tool like jvisualvm?

Comment: I just printed time at entry and exit of JSP files taken from java Date object

Comment: please try jvisualvm or any other tool to find the root cause at low level. start date & end date in jsp may not give you low level details .